# Upgrading to Laravel 5.4.0 from 5.1

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am using Laravel 5.1 and I would like to know how to upgrade to the latest version of Laravel which is 5.4.

Can we directly upgrade to Laravel 5.4 From 5.1 ?

Comment: For best results you should follow the upgrade steps for each version. So upgrade 5.1 > 5.2 > 5.3 > 5.4

Comment: Like I have do the following steps:
Upgrading To 5.1 From 5.2
Upgrading To 5.2 From 5.3
Upgrading To 5.3 From 5.4

Comment: jfadich  there is no direct upgrading steps mentioned in laravel from 5.1 to latest..

Comment: correct because there isn't a good way to 'skip' to the latest version. You should upgrade to each incremental version.

Comment: The easiest way to jump from 5.1 to latest would be to install a fresh 5.4 install then copy your app code over, but I wouldn't recommend it as you lose you git history that way.

Comment: jfadich gotcha !! Thanks and please suggestion some other forums for asking laravel questions I am new to laravel that is why I am requesting.

Comment: [Laracasts](https://laracasts.com/discuss) Is a fantastic place to learn Laravel it also has a very active forum where you can ask for help. Here (Stackoverflow) is a good place for specific code questions too.

Comment: Thanks jfadich for helping and guiding.

Comment: Happy to help! (If my answer was sufficient please mark it as accepted)

Comment: Make sure you have a high enough version of PHP on your server.I started using Laravel on version 5.0 and had php 5.4 on it. I have updated each time a new Laravel version has come out and needed to go up to php 5.5 ( Laravel 5.1 ) and with Laravel 5.4 ( requires PHP >= 5.6.4 ) decided to go to php 7.

Comment: @jfadich I already up your answer.And Scott Thanks for more explanation.

Comment: I mean accept the answer (give it the green check), not just upvote it.

Comment: Done thanks once again.

Comment: Thanks. Welcome to Laravel!

Comment: [Laravel Shift](https://laravelshift.com) is an online service that can help you automate this process. Full disclosure, I'm the creator - made it cause my time is better spent building features, not following mundane upgrade steps.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The best way to upgrade is to follow the steps for each version. So upgrade to [5.2](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/upgrade) then [5.3](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/upgrade) then finally [5.4](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/upgrade). The upgrade guides look lengthy but it most cases it wont take to much time because the guide covers all potential changes but they won't all apply to your application.

Alternatively you could install a fresh version of 5.4 then copy your application code into the new Laravel. Since the upgrade for each version is relatively straight forward and this method would lose your git history I wouldn't recommend it.

Another paid method would be to use [Laravel Shift](https://laravelshift.com/) which will automate the upgrade process for you.

Edit: As @Scott mentioned you should make sure your server meets the [server requirements](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/installation#server-requirements) for your target Laravel version. Specifically make sure you have PHP >= 5.6.4 installed

Answer (score 0):

Well, you first you need to update your composer.json file. Around line 9, you should be requiring in the framework itself. Change that to use version 5.4.*. After that, run a composer update and then, yes, you do need to go through your files manually to address any incompatibilities.
after you replace provider folder to the new version.
https://github.com/laravel-shift/laravel-5.4/tree/master/app/Providers.

Comment: Hi, could you elaborate a bit more on addressing those incompatibilites? I'm thinking on taking SB Admin panel which got stuck on L5.0.*  and upgrading on L5.4.* before I start with a new project. Thank you.